# MySQL Replication fails - commands received in wrong order?

Tags: mysql, replication

The other day, I had this issue with one of our MySQL 5.1.60 master and 5.1.61 slave setups:

```
Last_Error: Error 'Can't create table 'foobar.#sql-4b87_2' (errno: 150)' on query.
Default database: 'foobar'. Query: 'alter table picture add index FKDD905 (pictureSource_id), 
add constraint FKDD905 foreign key (pictureSource_id) references picturesource (id)'
```

Got to mention, that we just "host" the MySQL servers/setups; the content (including INDEXes and such) comes from the customer. We just run it.

Okay, so here's what happened, as far as I understand it:

1. On the master, the customer created the table "`picturesource`"
2. On the master, they added the index "`FKDD905`" to the table "`picture`", referencing the field "`id`" from "`picturesource`" as a Foreign Key
3. The slave tried to execute "`alter table add index…`".
4. The slave tried to execute "`add table picturesource…`".

In that order.

On the slave, that failed. It failed, because **the table picturesource did not exist *on the slave***. How can that happen? Why did the slave try to add the index BEFORE creating the table? I mean, on the master, the table MUST have existed before they added the key.

Don't know if it's important, but `binlog_format = MIXED`. I manually added the (empty) table `picturesource` and could then restart the slave process (→ `START SLAVE;`). In a subsequent `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\G`, I then saw, that it did a **copy to tmp table** for the `picture` table; the `picture` table is huge (~7 GB).

Can someone clarify?

Comment: When you created table on the master the replica already worked without any errors? Are you using replicate-ignore-table?

Comment: I did not create the table on the master. It was there. To fix it, I created it on the slave. I am not usign replicate-ingore-table. Added steps 3 & 4 to how things happened.

Comment: To clarify - on the replica, the table `picture` existed. Not `picturesource`. `picturesource` existed on the master. That's why the customer was able to add the index `FKDD905` to the table `picture.